# Wrapping python doctest results that are longer than 80 characters

Tags: python, doctest, pep8

I'm trying to keep my source code under the 80 character *guideline* width that PEP8 recommends, but can't figure out how to wrap my doctest which has results longer than 80 characters.

A noddy example:

```
def long_string():
    """
    Returns a string which is wider than the recommended PEP8 linewidth

    >>> print long_string()
    0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

    """
    return '0123456789' * 10
```

I've tried a couple of combinations, including using `# doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE` and trying to simply wrap the line with a newline.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just figured out:

```
def long_string():
    """
    Returns a string which is wider than the recommended PEP8 linewidth

    >>> print long_string()
    01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\
12345678901234567890123456789

    """
    return '0123456789' * 10
```

Hope that helps somebody else out.

Comment: Generally, I avoid such issues in doctests by changing my expectations. `res = long_string(); print res[:60]` followed by the first 60 chars, etc.

Comment: Yeah that is certainly one approach. I'm actually documenting a default value that I would like user to see in the docstring, but I don't want it to become stale.

Comment: Using an ellipsis in the result might be an alternative solution if you do not care about the exact result, e.g., write `012345678901234567...0123456789` as the expected result.

Comment: [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest.ELLIPSIS) needs to be enabled by adding the [`# doctest: +ELLIPSIS` directive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest-directives) to the end of the code line that produces the output.

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by **davitenio** and **qris**, I would recommend using the [`#doctest: +ELLIPSIS` directive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest-directives), like so.

```
>>> from test.test_ppp import MockForm
>>> form = MockForm(mock_file='no-errors.xlsx')
>>> form.get_languages(settings_default='English', survey_header=
... form.metadata['raw_data']['survey'][0])  #doctest: +ELLIPSIS
['Ateso', 'English', 'Luganda', ... 'Runyoro-Rutoro']
```